# ZF2: Get url parameters in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

I have experienced Zend Framework 1 and I've build some apps with that framework.

Now, I'm experimenting Zend Framework 2, but I'm stuck on the url parameters.
I've setup my routing like this:

```
// Setup for router and routes
'Zend\Mvc\Router\RouteStack' => array(
    'parameters' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'default' => array(
                'type'    => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/[:slug]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                    'slug' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_\/-]*'
                    ),
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Htmlsite\Controller\BootController',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    'slug' => 'home'
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        'home' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Htmlsite\Controller\BootController',
                    'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

As you can see, I've tried to make a variable slug.
How can I access this variable?

Comment: For archive purpose: Very complete answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077126/how-to-access-route-post-get-etc-parameters-in-zend-framework-2

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-149):

```
$slug = $this->getEvent()->getRouteMatch()->getParam('slug');
```

More documentation [here](http://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/apidoc/index.html), but it looks kind of incomplete.

Answer (score 55):

Or simply:

```
$slug= $this->params('slug');
```

Answer (score 27):

Why not this one:

```
$this->params()->fromRoute('slug');
```

Comment: This is the preferred method now.

Answer (score 20):

you can simply use this as well

```
$this->params()->fromQuery('slug',null);
$this->params()->fromPost('slug',null);
```

I hope it works...