# Zf2 - get controller name / action name using uri

Tags: zend-framework2

Is there any way to get the controller name and action name using a given uri?

Example:

```
uri: http://test/client/edit/48
```

Controller name => client
Action name => edit

Comment: it's impossible to do via the actual URL string if that's what you are asking? This is because you can have any URL you want with any amount of segments depending on your Route config. You should use the method blow using RouteMatch :)

Answer (score 11):

You can match your uri against the application router to get a `RouteMatch` object.

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\Request();
$request->setUri($uri);
$router = $serviceLocator->get('Router');
$routeMatch = $router->match($request);
```

Now you can retrieve your params.

```
if ($routeMatch) {
    $controller = $routeMatch->getParam('controller');
    $action     = $routeMatch->getParam('action');
}
```

Comment: First, thanks for the answer! The problema is that to use the match procedure, we need a Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface. How can we build a  object that implements this interface using a given uri?

Comment: You can use the `\Zend\Http\Request` class. I have edited my answer. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

In your controller add these:-

```
use Zend\Stdlib\RequestInterface as Request;
use Zend\Stdlib\ResponseInterface as Response;
```

Then create a dispatch function in your controller

```
public function dispatch(Request $request, Response $response = null)
{
    $controller = $this->params('controller');
    $action = $this->params('action');

    echo "Controller: " . $controller . " Action: " . $action;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though late, but to help new visitors, resolved ans here,

[ZF2: Get url parameters in controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024969/zf2-get-url-parameters-in-controller)

in short, this code should help,

```
$controller = $this->params()->fromRoute('RouteParamForController');
```